# Question about proof in commutative algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Hey I have a question about how to continue a proof in commutative algebra. Suppose you have a Ring $R$ and a maximal ideal $m$. I want to proof that $(mR_m)^n=m^nR_m$. One direction is obvious. For the other direction you take $a^n r\in m^nR_m$. It is easy to show that this is in $(mR_m)^n$ if $r$ is a unit. If it is not then it is in $m$ as everything outside of $m$ is inverted in $R_m$. But what do I do with that...I think its probably trivial, but I don't know how to finish of the proof. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You appear to have a *misunderstanding* of what a power of an ideal means: $m^n$ is not the set of $n$-th powers of elements of $m$.  It is the set of sums of finitely many $n$-term products of elements of $m$, or in other words $m^n$ is the ideal generated by $n$-term products of elements of $m$.  Review what the meaning of a product of ideals $IJ$ is: it is ideal generated by  all products $xy$ where $x \in I$ and $y \in J$, and $I^2$ is the ideal generated by all products $xy$ where $x \in I$ and $y \in I$ (not the ideal generated by all $x^2$ for $x \in I$).

Comment: @KCd Oh men that was a stupid mistake. Are they then the same by definition?

Comment: No, not by definition.  And what you ask about is true for all localizations, not just at maximal ideals:  for any ideals $I$ and $J$ and multiplicative set $S$ in $R$ that  $(IS^{-1}R)(JS^{-1}R) = (IJ)S^{-1}R$, so localizing a ring sends products of ideals to products of ideals, but you have to genuinely understand what the notation all means before you work out a proof of that.

Comment: You are right. I think i got it. Thank you!